# Naming a generic Action/Method

Tags: c#

With a code sample something like this:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action action = () =>
        {
            var x = 1;
            x++;
        };

        Console.WriteLine(action.Method.Name);
    }
```

Will output: `<Main>b__0_0`

Is it possible to give this action a name so in more complex solutions it could be utilized more intuitively. For example being able to produce better Exceptions or stack traces.

Comment: The answer is no, its compiler generated, to do this you would need to edit the compiled code. However, depending on the use case you could use a local method, however i am sure that is not going to solve your problem. There has been talk about applying meta data to lamdas and so forth, but i don't believe there is any will to implement this

Answer (score 3):

By definition, the lambda expression is compiled into an *anonymous* method. Of course, that's a bit of a misnomer. The method does have a name, but this name is assigned by the compiler and as far as the rest of the compiled code goes, the method has no name at all. So, no…you can't change the name.

However, if you are using C# 7 or later, you have access to named [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions). Such functions can still capture local variables and otherwise behave a lot like an anonymous method. In your example, this might look like this:

```cs
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    void M()
    {
        var x = 1;
        x++;
    };
     
    Action action = M;

    Console.WriteLine(action.Method.Name);
}
```

Then you can provide whatever meaningful name you want (presumably something more meaningful than `M` :) ), and that will be shown in the `MethodInfo` object for the delegate.